# No consigo convertir una string en PHP

Tags: php

Llevo un buen rato intentando hacer una copmparacion y no lo consigo. Al intentar convertirlo en numerico pierdo el valor:
Mi programa

```
$actualizar = pedir($rutaPideVer);
$numer=(int)$actualizar;
var_dump(intval($actualizar));
var_dump($actualizar);
var_dump($numer);
if ($actualizar == "1"){
    echo 'despues--->'.$actualizar;
    if (floatval($actualizar) > 0) {
        echo "-----------Actualizacion de version ------------------------";
        actualizarProgramas($ruta);
    }
}
```

La variable `$actualizar` recibe un `1`, pero no consigo que funcione nada.

Esta es la salida que obtengo:

```
$ php actualizaVersion.php

int(0)
 string(4) "1"
 int(0)
```

Naturalmente el "if" esta dando false, y como podeis ver, el paso de `$actualizacion` a `$numer` falla.

El metodo pedir hace:

```
function pedir($ruta, $fichero = null)
```

{

```
// Get cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ruta);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'User Agent X');

if (null != $fichero) {

    $fp = fopen($fichero, "w"); // abrimos un fichero donde guardar la descarga de la web
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // determina donde guardar el fichero
}

// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
if (null != $fichero) {
    fclose($fp); // se cierra el manejador de ficheros
}
return $resp;
```

}

¿Me podéis indicar por donde buscar?

*Nota*: `$actualizar` recibe el valor 1 via http. El programa que envia el valor hace:

```
 if ($current > $versionRemota) {
            $actualizar = 1;
        }
    }
    header('Content-type: text/plain ;charset=utf-8');
    echo $actualizar;
```

Comment: Prueba: `trim( pedir($rutaPideVer) )`... lo que no coincide en tu resultado es que tengas `int 0` y tener un `string 4` con solo `"1"`

Comment: Con el trim, sigue dando el mismo resultado. Acabo de probar cargando un 1 en $actualizar, y entonces va; el problema es que lo que me llega por red, aunque solo se ve un 1, debe haber algo mas....

Comment: Prueba a ponerle el charset, puede que sea un problema de codificación: `header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    echo $actualizar;` Y dinos si no hay nada más en el método `pedir()`, dado que veo un `if` y no se sabe si en tu caso el código sigue otro camino que no es mostrado aquí donde el dato puede ser manipulado.

Comment: Utilizo CURL para acceder al servidor y retorna  `$resp = curl_exec($ch);`

Comment: ¿cURL dijiste... ? entonces pone el código cURL que estás usando. A mi me parece un problema con la codificación o que el dato es manipulado en el origen antes de ser devuelto. Sin ver por entero lo que hace `pedir()` no podemos determinar el problema.

Comment: Modificado charset, pero sigue igual.;

Comment: He añadido a la pregunta el método "pedir"

Comment: No entiendo mucho. Antes hablabas de que retornabas un `1` desde aquí: `header('Content-type: text/plain ;charset=utf-8');
    echo $actualizar;` pero ahora dices que el `1` se retorna desde el cURL ¿?  Si lo que estás retornando es el valor de `$resp`, muéstranos lo que arroja un `var_dump($resp);` en la parte del  cURL para ver lo que hay en esa variable, pues estás manejando un archivo, no es lo mismo que imprimir un simple texto con `echo`

Comment: Me han pedido que añadiera la rutina pedir.... Si te fijas, 'pedir()' hace un `return $resp` y luego vemos que `$actualizar=trim(pedir(...)`luego, cuando hago el vardump de $actualizar estamos viendo $resp
Sin embargo el vardump de $resp justo antes del return es `
string(4) "1"
`

Comment: La respuesta no va en la pregunta, por eso la quite

Comment: Esta bien, asi la gente puede seguir buscando alguna solucion, que yo ya he encontrado, pero parece que no la se poner bien....vale!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoro que es lo que me estaba generando mal el CURL, pero ha sido cambiar la linea

```
$actualizar = pedir($rutaPideVer);
```

por

```
$actualizar = file($rutaPideVer);
```

y todo funciona según lo previsto....
Gracias a todos.

Comment: Es lo que te decía en un comentario, con el cURL estás manejando un archivo. Aunque funcione, no me consta que tu código esté optimizado de esa manera.

Comment: pues me encantaria ver tu propuesta

Comment: Para hacer una propuesta tendría que entender el contexto. Por ejemplo en tu código había incorporada una petición del tipo `cURL` que ofrece más posibilidades y es quizá más potente que `file`. Yo te pedí que mostrases un `var_dump($resp);` para ver lo que había allí pero no has mostrado nada. Entiendo que lo que quieres es traer un dato que hay ¿en un archivo? ¿en una fila del archivo? ¿El contenido completo del archivo? O sea, falta información con respecto al contexto.

Comment: Disculpa. $resp, contiene lo mismo que $actualizar. En esa etapa, quiero traer desde el servidor un marcador (me valdria true/false para saber si tengo que iniciar un proceso de actualizacion,,,,,
Si lo tengo que iniciar, en la siguiente interaccion, pedire un listado de una carpeta en donde estaran todos los modulos de la version, y en la ultima, ire solicitando los modulos uno a uno. Todo por http

Comment: No es posible que tenga lo mismo, de ser así el código funcionaría. En la programación hay que ser objetivos, te pedí que mostraras en resultado de `var_dump($resp);`, si fuera algo como `string(1) "1"` funcionaría. Si arroja otra cosa entonces hay que ver por qué está arrojando eso.

Comment: Ya, de ahi mi problema, fijate que en "pedir" hago "return $resp, y por otra parte, hago $actualizar=pedir(....)

Comment: Pero en `pedir();` la variable `$resp` está adquiriendo un valor distinto al que esperas, por tanto debes probar esa variable ahí, en `pedir()`, haciendo un `var_dump($resp);`

Comment: Te aseguro que ya lo he hecho, y por eso estoy afirmando que contiene lo mismo que $actualizar